# tkinter give window focus

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a tkinter python 2.x program.  I have several windows appearing on the screen.  I use buttons to navigate from one to another, but I'm struggling to close a window and refocus on a currently opened window.  I can open new windows just fine!

```
#code for main window
def frmMain():
  app = Tk()
  app.title("TWS: XML Options")
  app.geometry("200x100")
  bn1 = Button(app,text="Add", command=frmAdd)
  bn1.grid(row = 2,column = 2, stick = W)
  bn2 = Button(app,text="Edit", command=frmEdit)
  bn2.grid(row = 2,column = 3, stick = W)
  bn3 = Button(app,text="Delete", command=frmDelete)
  bn3.grid(row = 2,column = 4, stick = W)
  bn4 = Button(app,text="Back",command=frmMenu)
  bn4.grid(row = 3,column = 2, stick = W)
  app.mainloop()

#code for button on sub window
....
bn1 = Button(app,text="Back", command=back)
...

def back():
   #Code to close current window and reopen frmMain
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call [`destroy()`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/toplevel.htm) on widget's parent.

```
bn1 = Button(app, text="Back", command=app.destroy)
```

I suppose you are not destroying the parent window, so once the Toplevel is destroyed, the focus is automatically returned to the previous opened window.

Comment: if there are say 5 windows open, and you have a form linking them all together, how do you get to focus to fall on a specific window, rather than the last one to be opened?

Comment: Then you need a reference to the specific window, and then call `mywindow.focus_set()` before destroying the current window.

Comment: How would you get the reference to frmMain in the above code?  Something like myWindow = get.title("TWS: XML Options")

Answer (score 0):

A *TopLevel Window* can be activated using its [`deiconify()`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/wm.htm#Tkinter.Wm.deiconify-method) method.

Use the basic *Widget* method [`focus_set()`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.focus_set-method) to set keyboard focus to a specific widget.

Comment: Didn't work for me on OSX. I also tried `focus_force()`, which also didn't work. I'll probably resort to a platform specific solution to make this work on OSX.